# Image does not show at product in odoo

Tags: html

There is one bug at my product module...

Iam creating a product from website fronted When I click a button from website fronted then a product will be created at sales product.

It is working fine. I am sending image binary format to the product image field image_medium. But in product image is not visible...
And I am also tested when I import the product from csv file. In that time also product image is not visible.

Please any one help to rectify this bug.

id :
475

name :
Pencil

image_medium :
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

Comment: When product was created on sales product at that time images are visible on backend under the sales/produts menu.....?

Comment: thanks for ur reply. No it is not visible

Comment: if there is no image for a product it shows like camera symbol. But after created product that symbol is not showing and image pic also not visible

Comment: Are you trying to load image through csv file or you manually applied...??

Comment: manually it is showing.. using csv file is not visible

Comment: Can you show your csv file example...?

Comment: ok, i will add the csv file data

Comment: change your column name "id" , "name" , "image" and then tried.

Comment: for this data product is created maulik but image is not visible...  "id" like this when i import in product there is no effect

Comment: Did you converted product image in base64 formate....?

Comment: yes product image is base64 format...                  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kEtURatk_Q     in this link product is imported from csv file. i also do like this but it is not work for me... please can u check this video

Comment: you getting the problem because of your code is not properly converted in base64 formate so just convert your image through this link [LINK](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/) i hope this will help you Tejaswini.

Comment: Thanku so much maulik its working........

Comment: Your Welcome Tejaswini.

Comment: If you got the solution then just 'mark' this answer so other can save their time and also get the help from your query. :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a issue of your image decoding, so decode your image using this [LINK](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/image-to-base64/)

You will get the output.